# How set value for matInput

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular2-forms

How set value for the Angular Material input field. Then from my component I get data from my db as a json object and I want to set those are as values in the Angular Material form input feild.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/passenger/2/getPassenger').
  subscribe(
      response => {
        this.data = response.json();
      }
  );
```

how pass values in the form.

Comment: Do you mean, can you write the PHP for me?

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using a form input, use Angular's ReactiveForm's.

Import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`.

In your component create a service to hold your form group like:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {

    public formGroup = new FormGroup({

        name: new FormControl('', [

            Validators.required,

        ])

    });

}
```

Now in your api call reference your service and update the value:

```
...
constructor(myformService: MyFormService) {}

yourApiCall() {

this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/passenger/2/getPassenger')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.myformService.formGroup.controls.name.setValue(response.name);
        });

}
...
```

And in your component reference your form group:

```
<form [formGroup]="myformService.formGroup">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

See the official angular documentation for more information: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

at first glance it looks like you're forgetting to map the response to json...

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/v1/passenger/2/getPassenger')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.data = response.json();
        });
```

at this point your "data" var will have the json you want..
then on your template you can go a few different ways in angular.. here's a simple one

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let user of data">
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
</mat-form-field>
```

UPDATE:
in order to do so you have to add rxjs module to your project...

```
npm install --save rxjs
```

and import it on your *.component.ts file

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

you might have to add Observable as well tho it probably works without

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: ManageComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Comment: you have to npm install --save rxjs and import it's map.. editing answer

Comment: I got the answer and admire your response about my question.

Comment: core.js:1440 ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function why this kind of error get now

Comment: nope. `ngModel` is being deprecated in angular 6+. not a solution.